# Join Partitions in Spark SQL for better performance

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL. I have a question on partition usage during Joins

Assume that there is a table named `test1` that saved on `10` partitions (parquet) files. Also assume that `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 200`.

Question:
If test1 is used to `Join` to another table, will Spark perform the operation using `10` partitions (which is the number of partitions the table resides), or will it repartition the table anyway in `200` partitions (as per shuffle partition value) and then perform the join ? in which case the join will yield better performance. If the answer is that the join will be performed using the `10` partitions, isn't it better to always repartition (`CLUSTER BY`) the joining table to a higher number of partitions for better Join performance ?

In the Spark UI I have seen some `stages` using only `10` `tasks`, while other `stages` using `200` tasks.

Can someone please help me understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark will use 200 partitions in most cases (SortMergeJoin,ShuffleHashJoin), unless spark estimates your table to be small enough for a BroadcastHashJoin

Answer (score 0):

Spark will read the data in 10 partitions on 10 tasks and similarly it would read the other data frame partitions used in the join and once it has all the data it would create 200 partitions which is the default value for shuffle partitions. So this is the reason you see 10 tasks in one stage, then some other tasks in different stage and then finally 200 tasks after the shuffle operation. So at last after join you would have 200 partitions by default unless you have set that to different value in spark configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if there is any way in `Spark UI` to look at any particular running `stage` and tie it back to my spark sql code and understand which part of that code is running ?

Comment: @matthew it is possible to see that in the Spark UI but you will require better understanding of the spark architecture. You get the details of the job that is created along with the number of stages that are present in that job etc. To get use to that try with small dataset or chunks and see if you start figuring the stuffs.